# Dynamic multi level hierarchy JSON to Java Pojo. Re-use for multiple projects

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have JSON like below

```
{
    "name" : "sahal",
    "address" : [
        {
           "state" : "FL"
        },
        {
           "country" : "FL",
           "city" : {
               "type" : "municipality",
               "value" : "California City"
           }
        },
        {
           "pin" : "87876"
        }
    ]
}
```

None of the key:value is constant. Name can change any time. And some time name comes like `FirstName`.

I tried with  @JsonAnySetter  and  @JsonNode. These works with only one hierarchy

Any other way I can do this and reuse it for other JSON structure without writing the
Pojo for each projects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use JsonNode and fuse a hierarchy loop to extract all the keys and values dynamically regardless of patterns and relations and values,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        //which hierarchy is your json object
        JsonNode node = nodeGenerator(hierarchy);
        JSONObject flat = new JSONObject();
        node.fields().forEachRemaining(o -> {
            if (!o.getValue().isContainerNode())
                flat.put(o.getKey(), o.getValue());
            else {
                parser(o.getValue(), flat);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(flat);
        System.out.println(flat.get("type"));
    }

    public static JsonNode nodeGenerator(JSONObject input) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readTree(input.toString());
    }

    public static void parser(JsonNode node, JSONObject flat) {
        if (node.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode array = node.deepCopy();
            array.forEach(u ->
                    u.fields().forEachRemaining(o -> {
                        if (!o.getValue().isContainerNode())
                            flat.put(o.getKey(), o.getValue());
                        else {
                            parser(o.getValue(), flat);
                        }
                    }));
        } else {
            node.fields().forEachRemaining(o -> flat.put(o.getKey(), o.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

Which in your case extracted json will be as follow :
[image]

Comment: I trying to do JSON to Object. Initial JSON is the string to my project. How do I create hierarchy object first ?

Comment: Also I want to read it like flat.get("address")[1].get("city").get("value")

Comment: @Sahal Its quiet easy, create JsonObject as  JSONObject hierarchy = new JSONObject("Your Json string");

Comment: How about my other question - Also I want to read it like flat.get("address")[1].get("city").get("value")
this is important to me

Comment: @Sahal i guess as the place that the input json may vary and have different structure and hierarchy even with use of builder pattern with having the "get(String key)" method on its interface extracting values may be troublesome, i recommend that  we create chat and discuss more on the chat, meanwhile if the answer was satisfy your first question i appreciate if you accept it as answer .